# Getting the text value selected in at ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a list box

```
  <Label Content="Report" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="36,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="84,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="-1">
        <ListBox Height="100" Width="100" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxFAT" Content="FAT"/>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxNUMI" Content="NUMI"/>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxSSID" Content="SSID"/>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxFact" Content="FACT"/>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBox>
```

This was created by dragging the listbox icon from the tool bar.  I added items and their values.
Now I am trying to just get the text value of the selected item.

```
 private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (string)ListBox1.SelectedValue;
        MessageBox.Show(text);
```

I have also tried SelectedItem

```
string text = (string)ListBox1.SelectedItem;
```

But the message box is always blank.
This should be simple, but I have been working on it for hours, and trying every suggestion or answer on stackoverflow.  Most suggestions do not even compile.  For example:

```
  string selected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Will not compile.  GetItemText is not found.  I am using Visual Studio 17. "'ListBox does not contain a definition for 'GetItemText'..."

Any thoughts?  Please advise. Thanks.

Thanks for the comment, Charles.  I did that.
Playing further, now I get

> ```
> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' to type 'System.String'.'
>
> string text = (string)ListBox1.SelectedItem;
> ```

Comment: Your problem is more that your items are not contained inside Listbox1, you have them inside a second listbox that is contained within Listbox1. Remove the 3rd and 8th line in your original example and see if that gets you further along.

Comment: `string text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Comment: or better `string text = (ListBox1.Selecteditem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();` to give you the content of the selected item.

Comment: Charles May - your comments are exactly the same as SharpNip's answer.  I gave him credit for the answer.  You should have answered instead of commented!  But I will upvote your comments!

Comment: No problem, just saw the issue and thought a comment would suffice in getting you moving forward again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Charles May, your XAML shows that your ListBox is within another ListBox, which is why you're getting errors being raised..

The event being called "ListBox_SelectionChanged_1" is bound to the ListBox object inside ListBox1, which is unnamed.

I believe that the behaviour you are looking for would be fixed like this:

XAML:

```
<Label Content="Report" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="36,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="84,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="-1">            
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxFAT" Content="FAT"/>
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxNUMI" Content="NUMI"/>
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxSSID" Content="SSID"/>
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxFact" Content="FACT"/>            
    </ListBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   string text = ((sender as ListBox)?.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Content.ToString();
   MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Or at least something close to this solution.

Comment: The code behind result is : System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' to type 'System.String'.'

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I edited the response correctly. Momentary brainlapse.

Comment: Hooray!  It works.  string text = ((sender as ListBox)?.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Content.ToString();  But comment on my part is to wonder where the C# Microsoft people are thinking?  I mean, shouldn't getting the selection of a list box be, maybe, easy?  And would the StackOverflow supervisors tolerate an opinion comment in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

In the markup, `SelectedIndex` is set to -1 which means there is no selection. In this case, `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` both return null. You can solve this either by setting `SelectedIndex` to a value between 0 and 3 or by preparing your code to cope with a null value in `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`, e.g.

```
string text = (ListBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Content?.ToString();
```

This won't raise an error so that the user can select an item afterwards. With a selection, the text should be displayed as expected.

Comment: I set SelectedIndex to 0 in the markup.  First, I get the error when I click on one of the selections, so the selectionIndex should never be -1 when SelectionChanged is raised.  Also, I set SelectIndex to 0 anyway and still not behaving.  Also, your suggestion does not compile.  string text = (ListBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Text; "Text" is underlined.  ListBoxItem does not contain a definition for Text....